# Using copy to copy specific files (based on filenames) from several directories to one directory, remove timestamp and keep filename and extension

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to copy specific files (search is always based on filenames) from 2 sub-directories (archive and archivestore) located in 1 directory (source) and copy them to another directory (SaveHere) by keeping the filename and extension but removing timestamp.

Tried the below script but it didn't work:

```
copy U:\clients\source\archive\ + U:\clients\source\archivestore\SampleFileName.file__01-02-2019_22-35-11-444_A X:\SaveHere\*.file
copy U:\clients\source\archive\ + U:\clients\source\archivestore\SampleFileName2.file_19-04-2019_20-35-56-676_A X:\SaveHere\*.file
pause
```

I expect that scripts checks both sub-directories (archive and archivestore) for the specified file names (SampleFileName.file_01-02-2019_22-35-11-444_A and SampleFileName2.file_19-04-2019_20-35-56-676_A)  and wherever the files are found, to be copied to the targeted directory (`X:\SaveHere\`) with date-stamps (`_01-02-2019_22-35-11-444_A` and `_19-04-2019_20-35-56-676_A`) removed and only filename with extension  remains (`SampleFileName.file` and `SampleFileName2.file`)

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate the files together? That's what `+` does with `copy`. Your question is very hard to read.

Comment: No, I use the + as to check both sub-directories but script copies completely different file rather than both or any of them.

Comment: You might want to read what `copy /?` says about `+`. As far as I know it does not do what you're hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. So I start with an example:

The directory `U:\clients\source` contains the **directories** and files:

- **archive**

  - SampleFileName.file__01-02-2019_22-35-11-444_A
  - SampleFileName2.file_19-04-2019_20-35-56-676_A
- **archivestore**

  - SampleFileName2.file_19-04-2019_20-35-56-676_A

The directory `X:\SaveHere` should contain after batch file execution:

- SampleFileName.file
- SampleFileName2.file ... *preferred from* directory `archive`.

**One** of lots of possible solutions for this file copying task is using loops:

```
@echo off
for %%I in ("SampleFileName.file" "SampleFileName2.file") do (
    for %%J in ("U:\clients\source\archivestore" "U:\clients\source\archive") do (
        for %%K in ("%%~J\%%~I_*") do copy /Y "%%K" "X:\SaveHere\%%~I" >nul
    )
)
```

The most outer **FOR** runs two times the second **FOR** with first `"SampleFileName.file"` and second `"SampleFileName2.file"` assigned to loop variable `I`.

The second **FOR** runs two times the third **FOR** with first `"U:\clients\source\archivestore"` and second `"U:\clients\source\archive"` assigned to loop variable `J`.

So the third **FOR** is executed in total four times with the wildcard patterns:

1. `"U:\clients\source\archivestore\SampleFileName.file_*"`
2. `"U:\clients\source\archive\SampleFileName.file_*"`
3. `"U:\clients\source\archivestore\SampleFileName2.file_*"`
4. `"U:\clients\source\archive\SampleFileName2.file_*"`

The third **FOR** searches for non-hidden files matching the current wildcard pattern and runs command **COPY** for each file found.

Command **COPY** copies the file found by third **FOR** to directory `X:\SaveHere` with destination file name as defined by first **FOR** assigned currently to its loop variable `I` with overwriting a perhaps already existing file with same name in `X:\SaveHere`.

**One more** solution is using just two **FOR**:

```
@echo off
for /R "U:\clients\source\" %%I in ("SampleFileName*.file_*") do (
    for /F "eol=| delims=_" %%J in ("%%~nxI") do copy /Y "%%I" "X:\SaveHere\%%J" >nul
)
```

The first **FOR** searches recursive in directory `U:\clients\source` and all its subdirectories for files matching the pattern `SampleFileName*.file_*` and assigns the found file name with full path to loop variable `I` before executing the second **FOR**.

The second **FOR** processes as string just the file name with file extension without path. It splits up to file name string into substrings using underscore as string delimiter. Just the first string underscore delimited string is assigned to loop variable `J` which is for the example once `SampleFileName.file` and twice `SampleFileName2.file`. Then second **FOR** runs the command **COPY** to copy the file with automatically truncated destination file name based on first underscore in source file name.

This solution does not work if there is an underscore left to date/time part in file name.

This solution has the disadvantage that the order of files found more than once in directory tree of `U:\clients\source` is not determined by the batch file code, but by the file system which returns the file names matching the pattern of first **FOR** loop.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>nul`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`